# Number format exception for large inputs

Tags: java, netbeans, biginteger, numberformatexception

This code works fine for some inputs. 
but I get a NumberFormatError for higher values of inputs such as 1000000.
The input (taken for s[]) ranges from values 1-2000000
What could be the reason?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */

       try
        {
         BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

         int no=Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());

         String s[]=read.readLine().split(" ");

         int result=0;

         for(int i=0; i<no; i++)
         {
             result+= Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
             if(result<0)
                 result=0;
         }
         System.out.println(result);

        }
        catch(IOException e)
       {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the input sample which gave you that exception?!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question? If so, please mark your favourite answer as resolved, and if not, please provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your for-loop, your first entered digit is the size of the array. That's how your logic is so far. Unless you're actually loading in 2,000,000 numbers manually (or copy/pasting), this would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You would get a `NumberFormatException` if you were to type in non-digits as the second input, or a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647) or less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648).

Entering something like:

```
1000000
2 1 2 1 2 1 /*... 999990 digits later ...*/ 2 1 2 1
```

makes the program terminate correctly. Here's the input file I used, if anyone wants it: http://ge.tt/95Lr2Kw/v/0

The program was compiles and run manually from a command promt like so: `java Solution < in.txt`.

Edit: I just remembered that the input values in the array could be as large as 2000000. You would have to use a `BigInteger` to hold a `result` value as large as 2000000^2.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @lzmaki.
I don't get any NumberFormatException for your value.
But, I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundException which actually caused from StackOverFlow when I tried like this:

```
1000000
1 2 3
then enter
```

as in that time, the system recognize that it have not enough memory in its stack for hold such huge number of data.

I got NumberFormatException for the following case:

```
1000000
enter twice
```

becuase not system get a non-number format to convert integer format which is "".

I hope my analysis help you to find your bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a buffer overflow, any non-numeric character passed to `Integer.parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException`. This includes whitespace and non-printable characters like newlines as well as decimal points (Since floating point numbers are not integers).

You can try validating your inputs by using `.trim()` when you call `read.readLine()`, as well as checking for null or empty string before passing to `Integer.parseInt()`. Something like:

```
     String input = read.readLine();

     if ( input != null )
         input = input.trim();
     if ( input.equals("") )
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must be a number");

     int no=Integer.parseInt( input );
```

However you decide to validate input for the first line, also do for the second readLine() call. Hopefully you can narrow down exactly what's causing the problem.