# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9646324351"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    String xString=String.valueOf(Math.abs(x));
    StringBuffer reverseX=new StringBuffer (xString);

    if (x>=Integer.MIN_VALUE & x<=Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        reverseX=reverseX.reverse();
        if (x<0) 
            reverseX=reverseX.insert(0,"-");

        return Integer.parseInt(reverseX.toString());
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Runtime Error Message:

> Line 12: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "9646324351"

Last executed input:

```
1534236469
```

What's wrong? help plz Orz!!!

Comment: which line is line 12?

Comment: Please add an [mcve]. And the complete stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number format exception for large inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607531/number-format-exception-for-large-inputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to call your method with the value:

```
reverse(9646324351);
```

You get an Compiler error, which leads you to the Problem:

> The literal 9646324351 of type int is out of range

So i do not understand why you can get an error in your method.

Use a long/Long or a BigInterger in your program

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm) you can rad about the data types and which range they cover

Comment: " _So i do not understand why you can get an error in your method_ " His input is `1534236469` which got reversed in his method to `9646324351`, that got rolled through `Integer.parseInt` (which is ofc above 2^31-1 range)

Answer (score 1):

That number is too large to be parsed as an Interger, it exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Rather use `Long.parseLong`

Comment: the range of int: –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647,

Answer (score 0):

Use biginteger class instead of Integer
Read the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public long reverse(int x) {
    String xString=String.valueOf(Math.abs(x));
    StringBuffer reverseX=new StringBuffer (xString);

    if (x>=Integer.MIN_VALUE & x<=Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        reverseX=reverseX.reverse();
        if (x<0) 
            reverseX=reverseX.insert(0,"-");

        return Long.parseLong(reverseX.toString());
    }
    else 
        return 0L;
}
```

You can try above code.

As this `9646324351` value is out of range of int type.You need to provide larger datatype for this String to numeric conversion.
As we know

```
double's range > long's range >int's range
```

Also you can try  [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Hope this will help you.